# Get SQL Server Response Time

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

How do you get the average response time for query a SQL 2005 server?

Comment: Can you define "response time"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Response time for what?  Opening a connection, executing a query, rolling back a transaction...?

You can get most information that you need from [**SQL Server Profiler**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187929.aspx) traces so long as you have the [**appropriate permissions**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187611.aspx) on the server.  In addition to SQL Profiler there are dozens of performance monitor counters.

Your average response time for query execution is going to depend on a lot of things.  Load on the server, size of your database, size and design of your tables and indexes, etc, all of which will change over time (sometimes even an extremely small amount of time).

Unfortunately there isn't a clear cut answer to your question.  I'd highly recommend that you read through performance tuning articles and get familiar with SQL Profiler and the perfmon counters.

Comment: response for query

Comment: SQL Server Profiler is the tool to use then: http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3750161/Introduction-to-SQL-2005-Profiler-Part-1.htm

Comment: I didn't consider profiler, since it places a load on the server.  Was hoping for a DMV or query solution.